# safe distance for re-drilling nail holes

Tags: wood, drill, hole

I drilled at wrong place inside the window frame when installing blinds, about 1/2 inch off, is it safe to drill a new hole 1/2 inch away from the old one?

edit:
Please see picture, it's another window in my home, all the window frames in my home are like this, I drilled the hole on the bottom of the top frame.

To be clearer, it's not nail hole, but screw hole, I already installed the bracket using screws, need to take them down. Do screw and nail make difference here?
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Hard to tell from your description. Do you have pics?  Are you worried about the frame or the blinds?

Comment: What's the wood? If it's oak, OK. If it's new big box store pine, I'd fill the old hole with epoxy first. Metal? AOK.

Comment: I am worrying about the frame, the hole is used to install the bracket that is holding the blinds head rail. I am not sure what type of wood. My home is newly built, IMO it's unlikely that the window frame is made of oak. I will fill the holes with wood filler, but I am not sure if I can fill the hole completely as the nail is 1 1/4 inches long, the filler may not go that deep, and I don't think the filler is very strong. BTW I am new to home DYI.

Comment: I'm surprised there is wood at all.  I would assume the window frame is drywall.

Comment: I will take a picture tonight

Comment: i like to go 4X the nail width as a minimum. for most nail then, a half inch is plenty.

Answer (score 2):

Putting another hole even 1/4" away would work at 1/2" I would not worry at all. So I would say it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

filling the "oops" with any type of putty is not going to do you any good.  There is no structural integrity with putty.  If you feel you need to fill the hole with something, get a very small piece of dowel rod glue it into the hole. After it dries you can drill anywhere you want.

Comment: What type of glue do I need, can you specify the name of the glue ?

Comment: any type of wood glue you can find.  Elmers or tightbond.  You can get it at most stores, walmart, home depot, ...  You could also use just plain old white school glue.  If it makes a bond, you are good.

Comment: I wouldn't over-tighten the new screws as you put them in.  Forcing them to be really tight will give you more of a chance of splitting the wood.